# How to manage multiple versions of the same NPM dependency?

Tags: javascript, npm, yarnpkg, bower, c3.js

##### Situation

I've written a bunch of [D3.js](https://d3js.org/) charts using the latest version of [D3 (4.9.1)](https://github.com/d3/d3/releases/tag/v4.9.1).

However I also need to include the occasional [C3.js](http://c3js.org/) chart in my app, problem is-  C3 requires [D3 v3.5.0](https://github.com/d3/d3/releases/tag/v3.5.17).

---

##### What I've considered so far

- Forking C3 to update it to the latest version of D3 (it's not really feasible though)
- Using a different package manager, such as Yarn
- Just forgetting about C3.... (don't want to do this, as it will involve a lot of re-work!)
- Specifying a URL of an older version in the bower.json. However, I still was not able to reference to just that version for C3, and the latest for everything else.

  ```
   "d3": "^4.9.1",
   "d3-3.5.0": "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.0/d3.min.js"
  ```

---

##### Question

Is it possible to manage multiple versions of the same dependency, cleanly?
And if not, what would be a sensible work-around?

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16156445/multiple-versions-of-a-script-on-the-same-page-d3-js

Comment: The workaround is to use NPM and build tool instead of Bower. C3 may have its own version of D3. It's not clear if you use Angular 4 or AngularJS. In the first case you already have Webpack, in the second `angular` tag is wrong, The tag is unnecessary here any way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### TLDR

> Aliased versions of a dependency can be created with both NPM or Yarn using:
>
> ```sh
> npm install <package_name_alias>@npm:<package_name>
> ```

#### Intro

Having multiple versions of the same dependency is really not ideal if it can be helped.
But if, for example you're migrating to the latest version of a given package, while continuing to support legacy features in the interim, then it may be necessary.

Ensure you're using a recent version of NPM (at least [`v6.9.0`](https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v6.9.0) when support for this was added).

#### Install

So, to for example install both Vue 2, and the latest Vue 3 with NPN [package aliases](https://github.com/npm/rfcs/blob/main/implemented/0001-package-aliases.md#detailed-explanation), we would do:

```sh
npm i vue
npm i vue-legacy@npm:vue@2.6.14
```

Or, with Yarn:

```
yarn add vue
yarn add vue-legacy@npm:vue@2.6.14
```

#### Import

Then, when it comes time to use the dependency,

```
import Vue from 'vue'; // Will use the latest version
import Vue from 'vue-legacy'; // Will use V 2.6.14
```

#### Package.json

In the package.json, this will look like:

```json
"dependencies": {
  "vue": "^3.2.33",
  "vue-legacy": "npm:vue@^2.6.14"
}
```

*You can also add this into your package.json manually, remove the lock file, and run `npm install` / `yarn` to fetch*

#### Alternate Sources

You can also install packages directly from GitHub using this method. Useful to get a specific version, even if not yet published to NPM, or if you wish to use your own fork of the project.

```sh
npm install package-name@github:username/repository
```